# Ошибка перегрузки операторов

Tags: c++

```
struct subject
{
    int c;
    int m;
};

const bool operator > ( subject* first, subject* second )
{
    return first->c > second->c;
}
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Overloaded 'operator>' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type.
> ```

Что не так?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/8491726

Answer (score 9):

Перегруженные операторы в языке С++ перегружаемы только для класс-типов или enum-типов. Любой перегруженный оператор должен иметь как минимум один параметр класс-типа или enum-типа (или являться ссылкой на такие типы).

У вас оба параметра перегруженного оператора имеют тип "указатель". Тип "указатель" не является ни класс-типом или enum-типом. Поэтому ваша перегрузка не является корректной.

Вот что не так.

А что с этим делать - зависит от того, чего именно вы пытаетесь достичь и почему вдруг вы пытаетесь перегрузить оператор именно для указателей. Ваш вопрос не очень-то богат деталями на эту тему.

Answer (score 6):

Агрументами в данном случае должны быть экземпляры или ссылки (лучше, константные), а не указатели. А вот const при возвращаемом значении - ни к чему. То есть:

```
bool operator > ( const subject& first, const subject& second )
{
    return first.c > second.c;
}
```